# Is there any way to Deep Link into Microsoft Azure Intelligent Hub application?

Tags: azure, react-native, deep-linking, url-scheme

We are building a ReactNative application, which redirects the user to install an app from the Intelligent Hub app if the app is not installed on the user's device.

**Problem:**
The RN application redirects to the Intelligent Hub app and opens the home screen in Intelligent Hub. We require the RN app to redirect to the specific app to be installed into the Hub app. As users do not need to navigate and search for the application in the Hub app.

I'm looking for the URL schemes for the Hub app. How we can add URL schemes or if they are already available.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Azure Workspace one Intelligent Hub provides URL schemes.

Url scheme for Intelligent Hub is in format (Below scheme works for both iOS and Android)
wsonehub://apps -  To deep-link to the apps screen.
wsonehub://apps/view/AppName -  To deep-link to any application installation page.

Below is the link for Android.
https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workspace-ONE-Intelligent-Hub/services/rn/Intelligent-Hub-for-Android-Archive.html?hWord=N4IghgNiBcIO4GcD2A7ApgCwK4CMQF8g

Note - Do not forget to add Intents in android and LSApplicationQueriesSchemes for iOS in plist file.

iOS
Add in plist file

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
 <string>wsonehub</string>
</array>
```

For **Android the URL scheme is not working**.